# Is it possible to configure proxy authentication username and password in windows?

Tags: proxy, ntlm, squid, proxy-authentication, internet-options

I have a squid proxy server with basic SQL db authentication. When setting it on a client machine, the user is prompted with a dialog that asks for the username/password.

When they are entered and the save box is checked, the prompt no longer appears in IE but chrome asks every time it is started.

My question - is it possible to preconfigure the username/password in registry or somewhere else? I have tried the

```
http://username:password@server:port
```

and variations of it with no success. When that string is entered the browsers ignore it completely and proceed with no proxy.

I looked into setting up ntlm on squid but it seems that if the client is on a different domain the user will still be prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the below steps to enforce IE using the same connection during the whole authentication procedure.

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click either of the following keys in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

1. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD.
2. Type ReleaseSocketDuring401Auth, and then press ENTER.
3. On the Edit menu, click Modify.
4. Type 0, and then click OK.

Microsoft Blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/03/28/ie-always-prompts-for-authentication-when-browsing-through-proxy-server.aspx